# React Reference equality issue on API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am developing an app with React calling CoinGecko API to display a list of cryptocurrencies with some infos. This is the useState, useEffect part.

```
     const [cgData, setCgData] = useState([]);

     const fetchData = () => {
        fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&sparkline=false', {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                setCgData(json);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [cgData.length]);
```

Using cgData only instead of cgData.length in the useEffect dipendencies causes infinite rerenders, because even if the values are the same, the reference is not the same.

The code works, but I am not sure this is the best practice for the problem.
How can I improve the solution?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: i guess you can leave the dependacy array empty,it will fetch all infos at once when component mounts

Comment: How often do you want `fetchData` to be called? Once when the component initially mounts? Or is `fetchData` being called from somewhere else too? You probably just need an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

So this happens because your observed variable is changed every time on the useEffect effect. Each time setState changes CgData, its pointer changes and retriggers useEffect.
If you only want to trigger this condition on first render, you should leave the condition array empty. If there are other situations where this should be triggered, then perhaps you should consider if cgData is what you should be observing, or if you should always update its value after doing a fetch.